Understanding the Cantors Diagonalization
I'm having difficulty re-understanding this as I took Real Analysis I years ago.
I understand the purpose of this diagram, in mapping N to R and finding a number on the diagonal not on our list. And we can create a new decimal number that no matter what will not match what the diagonal number is, etc.
My biggest question is why?
First off how is the new number we choose have relavance to the diagonals? Obviously the new decimal number we pick will not be on the diagonal list because we are choosing the digits to be different, but how does that show in terms of the diagram purposes that it will be different from the diagonals? These new digits we choose will not be on our list but how do these new decimal numbers we chose, relate to the original cantor diagram we created?
Two, why the diagonals? Why can't we choose a row or column to show this claim?

The list is meant to be exhaustive, so producing a real number not on the list is a contradiction.  But...this line of proof is very well covered online and in references, here for instance.  I don't think it's useful for anyone to try to summarize the arguments here.

I've looked online and have reviewed the topic the past few days and had these questions. The online references don't really explain why we choose the diagonals over choosing a row or column?

Mauro, I get that it's mainly why the diagonals that is being chosen? why not choose the rows or columns?

I have no idea what a column or row variant would look like, though it might be possible.  With the diagonal proof we can say that the new number differs from $F(n)$ in the $n^{th}$ entry....what would a column proof look like?  The new number is hardly going to be able to differ from all the $F(n)$ in the first entry or whatever.

No... The question is  why the cantor diagram is choosing the diagonal digits rather than choosing a row or column?

@Ryansmith The purpose of the proof is to show that the set is not enumberable. We assume to the contrary. Then, we construct a sequence that cannot be covered by our enumeration. This contradicts the assertion that our enumeration is exhaustive. The diagonal is convenient because it allows us to construct a sequence that is different from every sequence in the enumeration. Consider a different construction such that the new sequence differs from the ith sequence in the i + 1 element. That would also work.

I recommend stepping back and clarifying what exactly the method is intended to prove:

No map $f: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is surjective.

And the way we prove this is with a "challenge-response" pattern: Come up with a method that lets you exhibit a real number that is not in the range of $f$, if I challenge you with a function $f$ that I think is surjective.
Now we can answer your questions: The list (rows) is the range of a function $f$. The diagonalization method is the strategy to answer the challenge: for any $f$, you find a real number that is not in its range, ie not on the list, by going down the diagonal and changing each digit.
And why not a row or column? Because the rows are exactly the numbers in the range, so you can't answer the challenge by picking one of them. And you don't have a guarantee that the number you produce from a column is not in the range. Changing digits on the diagonal guarantees that the result is not in the range.
